# Windows Phone dynamics table

Tags: windows-phone, tabular

This is my first WinPhone application.

So, I need to create dynamics table. Create it programmatically, not from XAML.

Application will download some inforamtion from server and display it on table, that is why table has dynamical cell count.

It will looks like in this app:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

How should I do it? Give me some tutorial please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lot of samples that point to this solution. You need to get data from internet or any other source and then use ListBox control to bound to this data to get as you called "dynamic table" or list of rows that corespond to you data source.

You have examples on dev.windowsphone.com or on nokia.com:
**RSS Reader Silverlight** : http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/934cc415-474e-43a1-8edc-6d41aa238914/RSS_Reader_Silverlight.html
**RSS Reader Sample**: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/RSS-Reader-Sample-1702775f

Or I missed something in your question!

Hope this help
Best regards